# How do I merge a bulk number of commits at a time in GIT?

Tags: git

How do I merge a large number of commits in phases of, say, 20 commits at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git merge` accepts *any* commit specification, so you can do:

```
git merge ...
git merge origin/master~60
git merge origin/master~40
git merge origin/master~20
git merge origin/master
```

or even `git merge 357a887` to merge everything up to commit 357a887...

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do that? Mashing up the commits just gets rid of the history.

If you really do want to do this, I'd go for "git rebase -i" (interactive rebase), that alows you to go wild rewriting history (reordering commits, smashing them together,  delete some, ...). Splitting commits can be done, but it is a bit tricky.

I'd go like:

git branch save         # don't want to lose the original accidentally...

git rebase -i HEAD~20   # for last 20 commits

# Edit the offered template at will, minimal help included

# Exiting the editor makes git do as told, it might stop if manual intervention required